# Fix spacing on Overleaf with LaTex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am working on my resume and am using LaTex in Overleaf. I am having issue with spacing everything properly. Here is my LaTex.

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sidratul Muntaha Ahmed
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{1pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-6pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-9.5pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-10pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
        \end{tabular*}\vspace{-10pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-10pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-5pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------


\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Brad Bieselin} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \textbf{\small \scshape 516-557-8407 $|$ Wantagh, NY} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \href{https://bradbieselin.com/}{\underline{bradbieselin.com}} $|$ \href{mailto:brad@bradbieselin.com}{\underline{brad@bradbieselin.com}} $|$ 
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in/bradbieselin}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/bradbieselin}} $|$
    \href{https://github.com/bradbieselin}{\underline{github.com/bradbieselin}}
\end{center}


%-----------Experience-----------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Witbe Inc}{New York, NY}
      {Project Manager/Customer Success Manager}{June 2021-Present}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Led and managed 9 projects for customers including Verizon, ViacomCBS, and Peacock by automating VoD asset testing, Channel Change testing, and video/audio quality analysis using Witbe robots}
            \resumeItem{Prepared and facilitated 8+ hour interactive training sessions for all customers, including 10+ senior executives on delivery of new products and software}
            \resumeItem{Planned, scheduled and executed all software, hardware, and system integration with over 100 Witbe robots and customer devices to ensure the best Quality of Experience monitoring}
            \resumeItem{Established growth and generated improvements to customer business by over 40\% by managing automated scripting and monitoring projects, and finding opportunities for improvement}
            \resumeItem{Stimulated progress of each project to meet deadlines and standards with 10+ check-ins per week and constant improvemenets to automation scripts}
            
        \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
  
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Apple Inc}{Remote}
      {Software Quality Engineer}{February 2021-June 2021}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Developed projects in Java using Jackson, Jenkins, TestNG and Gradle which analyzed and validated Apple.com product prices when adding products to the cart, testing over 3000 scenarios}
            \resumeItem{Engineered a Full-Stack project which allows the upload and download of files, built with a React.js and Spring Boot backend, and using Amazon S3 cloud storage to store files}
            \resumeItem{Gained fluency in AWS with 40+ hours of training and obtained AWS Cloud Practitioner Certification}
            \resumeItem{Collaborated with development engineers for code review regularly to propose improvements}
            \resumeItem{Collected data, devised Confluence reports, and presented reports during weekly team meetings which highlighted progress of software quality testing projects}
            
        \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
  
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Frontend Web Developer}{}
      {Freelance}{January 2021-Present}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Coding web applications and integrating CMS driven data, such as Contentful}
            \resumeItem{Designing and creating user interfaces with modern frameworks including React.js and Next.js}
            \resumeItem{Completed FrontendMasters Bootcamp and 40+ hours of additional courses including Functional Javascript, Advanced CSS, Computer Science, and Website Accessibility}
            \resumeItemListEnd
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
  
  
%-----------Education-----------
\section{Projects}

    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\href{https://studentprofiles.bradbieselin.com/}{\underline{Student Profiles}} $|$ \emph{React.js/Firebase}}{}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Developed a website which lets users filter student profiles by name or tag and see test scores driven by an API, using React.js for the frontend}
          \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
    
    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\href{https://bitcointracker.bradbieselin.com/}{\underline{Bitcoin Tracker}} $|$ \emph{Javascript/Firebase}}{}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{An animated sunset built with Javascript, CSS, and HTML that tracks the live price of Bitcoin using the Binance.com websocket}
          \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%
%-----------Education-----------
\section{Education}

    \resumeSubHeadingListStart
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{University at Albany, SUNY} \emph{}}{May 2015-December 2019}
          \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Bachelor of Science in Computer Science}
            \resumeItem{Awarded from the College of Engineering and Applied Science}
          \resumeItemListEnd
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%
%-----------SKILLS-----------
\section{Skills}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \textbf{Languages}{: Javascript, TypeScript, CSS, HTML, Java, Python, C, LaTex, PowerShell, Bash} \\
     \textbf{Web Skills}{: WebPack, Babel, Tailwind, Styled Components, SEO, Contentful CMS, Amazon Web Services} \\
     \textbf{React Skills}{: Next, Gatsby, Material/Semantic UI} \\
     \textbf{Technologies}{: Git, WSL 2, VS Code/Studio, IntelliJ, Node.js, Express, Spring Boot} \\
    }}
 \end{itemize}


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

I can't get the spacing to work properly. For my projects, education and skills section there is a lot of empty space and I want everything to be much closer together. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

Here is an example of the spacing I am looking to achieve: [image]

Here is what the section I am having trouble with looks like: [image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot on which you mark which spaces you'd like to change? I can't see any excess white space.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added pictures to the original post, thank you!